# Sed edit selection before replace

Tags: unix, sed

I need to edit a sed selection before performing replace...kind of nested query

Here are the first two lines of file.csv

```
"some text over one line"||02/21/2015 00:00:00||54.34||0.234     
"some text over 
multiple
lines"||02/21/2015 00:00:00||64.24||0.432
```

I want to strip the line breaks out of the first column - everything before the first delimiter `||`

This command collects each column and allows me to reference them individually

```
sudo sed -i 's/\(.*\)||\(.*\)||\(.*\)||\(.*\)/\1||\2||\3||\4/g' file.csv
```

I now need to edit `\1` before replacing. Something along the lines of a further sed command `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' file.csv` - but only applied to `\1` not the whole file

The output should look like this

```
"some text over one line"||02/21/2015 00:00:00||54.34||0.234
"some text over multiple lines"||02/21/2015 00:00:00||64.24||0.432
```

Comment: Does it have to `sed`? It would be a lot easier to do in `awk`.

Comment: I'd probably be thinking `perl` and `Text::CSV` or `Text::ParseWords`

Comment: Doesn't need to be sed, that's just what I am used to. Open to whatever works as long as it can write back to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed can do it, however you have to play with hold space. Awk has `printf`, you can control the output format easier:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",(/^"/&&NR>1)?RS:"",$0}' file
```

Will work for the given example.

P.S. If you are looking for the sed-only solution, leave a comment, I am gonna remove the answer.

Comment: That does seem to work - could you add a quick explanation of how (so I know if it will generalize)? I'm not that familiar with awk but whatever works is great.

Comment: @PeteBurnap it checks if the BOL is `"`, if true, print a new line otherwise not. In this way to join.